# "Number two" or "Number 2" in this context?

Tags: numbers

In the context of defecating, is it "Number two", or "Number 2"?

I assume "No. 2" would be too technical-looking for this context. Urban Dictionary has entries for both "Number two" and "Number 2".

Comment: The title was a little vague, because I don't want faeces to go hot across the network.

Comment: Personally, I would use #2 and otherwise I wouldn't capitalise **number**. I also think the **2** is more **artistically graphic**.

Comment: @Peter as in literally use "#2", or the second option I presented?

Comment: Literally, more **compact** as it were, sorry for the ambiguity.  Just as #1, graphically can be related to the action. For me, by using the **hash** it signifies something ***different***...

Comment: Why does the hash make it signify something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example to follow up the comments:

I asked by son, who is learning to go to the bathroom by himself,

> "Was it a **#1** or a **#2**?"

he replied

> "**#3**, one plus two equals three"

I then knew we were ready for the long car ride.

In contrast to

> The word from **Number 10** is that the Prime Minister...

Comment: The technicalities of #1 and #2 on the ISS are explained around 5:20 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGP6Y0Pnhe4

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really have anything to do with the context of defecating, just with how we write out numbers.  It would be the same issue if we were writing "Here we see Engine Room #2/Number Two."   This is primarily a style issue, but in general we write out small numbers, particularly in nontechnical contexts.

The AP style guide says "Spell out whole numbers up to (and including) nine" and "Spell out casual expressions".  The Chicago Manual of Style says "Spell out whole numbers up to (and including) one hundred".  In general, I cannot think of any reason **not** to spell out "#2" in a short sentence representing actual speech.

Reference: [Numbers: Spell Out or Use Numerals? (Number Style 101)](http://www.apvschicago.com/2011/05/numbers-spell-out-or-use-numerals.html)

Comment: There are a few cases where I'd use "2" instead of "two." Here are two: _Remember to bring a No. 2 pencil to class. Eddie Shore wore number 2 for the Bruins_.

Comment: @J.R. - Good examples!  Those are both cases where "2" is something like   a label or title, I think.